# $f(f(x))$ has an unique fixed point, prove $f(x)$ has an unique fixed point too.

Tags: functions, fixed-points

> If $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and $f\circ f$ has an unique fixed point, prove $f$ has an unique fixed point too.

I've tried contradiction but only proved that $f(x)$ has at most one fixed point:

Suppose for contradiction that $f(x)$ has two different fixed point $a$ and $b$, thus we have $f(f(a))=f(a)=a$ and $f(f(b))=f(b)=b$, a contradiction.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You should include your proof that $f$ has at most one fixed point.

Comment: Hint: if $x$ is a fixed point of $f\circ f$, then so is $f(x)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Aha! I know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $a$ is a fixed point of $f\circ f\implies f\circ f(a)=a\implies f\circ f\circ f(a)=f(a)\implies f(a)$ is a fixed point of $f\circ f\implies f(a)=a$ since $f\circ f$ has a unique fixed point.

So $a$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Now you apply what you have done.

Comment: We don't know that $f(f(a))=a$ we only know that $f(f(a))=f(a)$

Comment: @BoboCarr; I dont know what you are saying  please point the exact step

Comment: @BoBo Carr This proof is correct. We know $f(f(a))=a$ precisely as Find_X says, both $f(a)$ and $a$ are fixed points and so they are the same since the fixed point is unique.

Comment: You start by supposing that $a$ is a fixed point of $f\cdot f$, but we are only given that $f(a)$ is the unique fixed point of $f(f(a))$

Comment: @BoboCarr the question presumes that $f(f(x))$ has a fixed point.

Comment: If $f(f(x))$ has a unique fixed point that only means that $f(f(x))=f(x)$

Comment: @BoboCarr;$f\circ f$ has a fixed point means $f\circ f(a)=a$ that does not mean $f\circ f(a)=f(a)$

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use the fact that if x is a fixed point of f then f(x) is a fixed point of f. Acoording to this, if a and b are fixed point of f we have that f(f(a))=f(a)=a and f(f(b))=f(b)=b. Since f(f(x)) have a unique fixed point we conclude that a=b.

There is a fixed point to f due to if x is a fixed point of f(f(x)) then f(f(f(x)))=f(x). So we have f(x)=x by the uniqueness of x

Comment: How do you know that $f$ has a fixed point

Comment: Yes. I just added that psrt

Comment: You should write the last part more carefully;there are some minor mitstakes