# Show that if $f(x)$ does not have a fixed point then $f(f(x))$ also does not have a fixed point

Tags: functions, fixed-points

> Show that if $f(x)$ does not have a fixed point then $f(f(x))$ also does not have a fixed point.

**Update**:

$f$ is continous

I tried proving this by contradicting [$f(f(x))$ has an unique fixed point, prove $f(x)$ has an unique fixed point too.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530128/ffx-has-an-unique-fixed-point-prove-fx-has-an-unique-fixed-point-too)
but no luck, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is $f$ a map from $\mathbb R$ into itself?

Comment: What is $f$ a function to or from?  In the finite field with $2$ elements, $f(x)=x+1$ has no fixed point but $f\circ f(x)=x+2=x$ does.

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be continuous?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The book dose not state anything about f being a map.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, $f$ is continious, I update the question. sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is a continuous function from an interval $I \subseteq \Bbb R$ into itself without fixed point then

- either $f(x) < x$ for all $x \in I$
- or  $f(x) > x$ for all $x \in I$.

In both cases, $f \circ f$ has no fixed point.

---

Without continuity the assertion is false:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{ if $x = 0$}\\
 -x & \text{ if $x \ne 0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
has no fixed point, but
$$
f(f(x)) = \begin{cases}
 -1 & \text{ if $x = 0$}\\
 x & \text{ if $x \ne 0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$
has infinitely many.

If the domain is not an interval then the assertion is also false, an example is
$$
 f: D \to D, x \mapsto -x \, .
$$
with $D = (-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$.

Comment: question has been update $f$ is continous

Comment: Thanks Martin..

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(f(p))=p$ for some $p$. Then, $f(f(f(p)))=f(p)$ so $f(p)$ is a fixed point of $f(f(x))$ as well. If you can prove that $f$ is such that, *if* $f(f(x))$ admits a fixed point, *then* this point is unique, then it follows that $f(p)=p$ and $f$ has a fixed point. For example, if $f(f(x))$ is a Banach contraction of a complete metric space, then the claim obviously holds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.