# How to prove the following statement

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f$ a continuous and defined function on $\Bbb R$ such as: $$(\exists a \in \Bbb R) \quad f \circ f(a)=a$$
Prove that :  $(\exists c \in \Bbb R) \quad  f(c)=c$

As a try, I've used the definition of continuity and I wonder if I'm able to put $f(c)=a$ or $f(a)=c$
, any idea ?

Comment: Is $a$ unique ?

Comment: unicity would trivialize the problem though...

Comment: @ThomasShelby Not necessarly

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220803/show-that-if-fx-does-not-have-a-fixed-point-then-ffx-also-does-not-hav?noredirect=1&lq=1 Take contraposition of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possibilities: (1) $f(a)=a$, (2) $f(a)<a$, (3) $f(a)>a$.

In case (1) we are done: take $c=a$.

In case (2) let $b=f(a)$, so $b<a$. We have $f(b)=a>b$. Now consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. We have $g(b)=a-b>0$ and $g(a)=b-a<0$. But $f$ is continuous, so $g$ must be continuous, so $g(c)=0$ for some $b<c<a$.

A similar argument works for (3).