# Show that $f(x)$ has a unique fixed point if and only if $f(f(x))$ has a unique fixed point.

Tags: metric-spaces

This question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530128/ffx-has-an-unique-fixed-point-prove-fx-has-an-unique-fixed-point-too) shows the first part, ie. $f(f(x))$ has unique fixed point $\implies$ $f(x)$ has a unique fixed point.

This is for a general **metric space** $(X,d)$, $f: X \to X$.

I want to prove the reverse implication that $f(x)$ has unique fixed point $\implies$ $f(f(x))$ has a unique fixed point.

I have tried to show that $g: X \to X$, $g(x) = f(f(x))$ is a contraction but I don't think this will help because $X$ is not necessarily complete.

Comment: Is this true?  over $\mathbb R$, we could have $f(x)=-x$. Then the only fixed point of $f(x)$ is $0$ but $f\circ f(x)=x$ has infinitely many fixed points.

Comment: That does seem right... The question reads "prove that $f$ has a unique fixed point if and only if $g$ has a unique fixed point" (where g is defined as above) but could be mistaken?

Comment: It is not **iff**. It is clear that any fixed point of $f$ is a fixed point of $f \circ f$, but not the other way around as the example $f(x) = -x$ shows.

Comment: Yes - that is a good example. I suppose there must be a mistake in the question I am looking at. Thank you.

Comment: Is there maybe a condition on $f$ such as that it is a weak contraction ($d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$ for all $x \neq y$)?

Comment: The question specifies no conditions on $f$ unfortunately. Do you have a condition in mind which would help?

Comment: That $f$ is a weak contraction for example. Then $f\circ f$ also is one, and hence it can have at most one fixed point.

Comment: Doesn't that require that $X$ is complete?

Comment: The uniqueness of fixed points (that there is at most one) doesn't require completeness. The existence of at least one fixed point of $f\circ f$ is _here_ given by the hypothesis that $f$ has a fixed point. Generally, for a _weak_ contraction, completeness is not enough to guarantee the existence of a fixed point, consider $X = [1,+\infty)$ and $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$. Then $f(x) > x$ for all $x$, but since $f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2} < 1$ for all $x$, $f$ is a weak contraction.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, the **if and only statement** is **not** true.

The example to disprove this statement is $f(x)=-x$ as the only fixed point of $f$ is $x=0$ by $f(f(x)) = -(-x)$ has infinitely many fixed points.

Thank you to @lulu.